# No route matches even though defined in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to use url_for in mailer view for a defined route:

```
<%= url_for(
    :controller => 'scribe_requests', 
    :action => 'accept', 
    :id => @match.acceptance_token, 
    :only_path => false) %>
```

I have defined the route in my routes.rb:

```
resources :scribe_requests do
  member do
    match 'accept' => 'scribe_requests#accept', :as => :accept
  end
end
```

And my controller:

```
class ScribeRequestsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def accept
    ..
  end
  ..
end
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here? My delayed job is failing with the exception

> "{No route matches {:controller=>"scribe_requests", :action=>"accept",
>   :id=>"nv4Nl8wWXLX2zFDm3s3t7w"}
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in
>   `raise_routing_error'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:528:in`
>   rescue in generate'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:520:in
>   `generate'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:561:in`
>   generate'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:586:in
>   `url_for'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in`
>   url_for'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:107:in `url_for'
>   /home/syed/work/projects/mapunity/retina-india/app/views/notifier/scribe_service_needed_email.html.erb:47:in`
>   _app_views_notifier_scribe_service_needed_email_html_erb___981003510_106966530'
>   /home/syed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in
>   `block in render'

Comment: did you try restarting your server?

Comment: does the route you want shows up in the rake routes command?

Comment: Yes. Tried after restarting and the route even shows up in rake routes.

Comment: Yes. The route shows in rake routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add `:via` option to the route definition and it worked. Weirdly, I had done that with no affect. May be some caching issue. So after the change, my route definition became,

```
resources :scribe_requests do
  member do
    match 'accept' => 'scribe_requests#accept', :via => :get, :as => :accept
  end
end
```

Test run:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > app.url_for :controller => 'scribe_requests', :action => 'accept', :id => 'test'
 => "http://www.example.com/scribe_requests/test/accept"
```

Thanks for the help.